# cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I was trying to fit my model into history, but my code didn't work. The initial error was

```
"Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at <ipython-input-10-fe8518c345fd>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_675]"
```

Then I tried using this code to reduce the memory

```
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
set_session(sess)
```

Then I got

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context' (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py)
```

Please help, I've been stuck in this hell for so long.

Version I am using:

python 3.8

tensorflow-gpu 2.4.1

cuda_11.2.2_461.33_win10

cudnn-11.2-windows-x64-v8.1.1.33

Comment: First of all there is no concept of `session` in `TF2.x`. Can you try as `physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU');
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available";
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)` and let us know?

Comment: @TFer2 I'm sorry, I tried that and still got the same problem. I ended up with avoiding the entire library import that made the error and working around it with other libraries. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: [I tried this and it worked for me. ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67618073/2702034)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run `Tensorflow 1.x` code in `Tensorflow 2.x`, which is causing this error.

You need to install `Tensorflow 1.x` in your system along with the compatible `python version 3.7` as per this [Tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) to run the above code.

You can install `Tensorflow 1.x` using the code below and restart the runtime(kernel).

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.15

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Also, make sure you are importing keras components [set_session](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/backend/set_session) correctly  along with prefix `tensorflow.keras`.

Fixed code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.backend import set_session
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
set_session(sess)
```

Attached a [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/3801725bc8e0a4688485c45c3ff0fa5c/66881794.ipynb) for your reference.