# ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My notebook was working up till today. At the beginning of my colab notebook I install tf-nightly, but now it is giving me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-589c442233c5> in <module>()
      7 import tensorflow as tf
      8 from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
----> 9 from keras.preprocessing import image
     10 from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator #check underscore or not
     11 from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py in <module>()
     35 from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribute_coordinator as dc
     36 from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribute_coordinator_context as dc_context
---> 37 from tensorflow.python.eager.context import get_config
     38 from tensorflow.python.framework import config
     39 from keras import backend_config

ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/context.py)
```

My code:

```
!pip install tf-nightly

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
from keras.callbacks import Callback, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping
```

Installing tensorflow==2.1.0 did not work either.

Comment: Uninstall tf-nightly if you don't need it.

Comment: I had the same issue trying to import the to_categorical() method from keras.utils.np_utils. I didn't find a direct solution, but I managed to bypass the error by importing it from tensorflow.keras.utils instead...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

These commands fixed the issue:

```py
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score 62):

Instead of:

```py
import keras
```

Try:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
```

Comment: Still the same error on your new line: cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py)

Answer (score 26):

**Try the version of Keras 2.3.1**

`pip install keras==2.3.1`

**then also install that**

`pip install git+https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git`

Answer (score 15):

instead of
`from keras.preprocessing import image`
do this:
`from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image`

Answer (score 6):

In my case with Google colab, I downgraded tensorflow to 2.2 and replaced all `import keras.xxxx` to `import tensorflow.keras.xxxx`. That fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

I've updated

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
from keras import layers, models, optimizers
from keras import backend as K
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
```

and it works :)

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this problem for myself.

```
# Instead of this:
from keras.preprocessing import image

# Do this:
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I changed the import from the following:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

To this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Comment: from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator - change it with from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

Comment: Please use comments section under the question post for "non-answer" comments like "In my case I changed to and it worked for me.", thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Works, but will interfere with the Tensorflow/NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit/NVIDIA cuDNN GPU-support set up.
Better solution: unistall Keras 2.6.0,
install Keras 2.4.3

The bug is fixed and GPU is running!

Answer (score 1):

I had `Tensorflow===2.2.0` and when I updated it to `Tensorflow==2.4.0` this issue occurred.

I think there is a conflict of `keras.models.load_model` and the base version of `tensorflow` you are using.

Try running -

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This strange problem corresponds with imports of tensorflow. If you change `from keras.preprocessing import image` to `from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image` it will work.

Answer (score 1):

For me it just work upgrading tensorflow. Note: if you're using special tensorflow as gpu version, you must update this one because it's a separate module.

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Then restart the kernal

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing tensorflow cpu with the instructions from anaconda. I used the following codes

```
from keras_preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras_preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Spyder by Mac. At the first time, no matter I installed `Tensorflow==2.1` or `Tensorflow==2.0.0`, which any version of Tensorflow, they didn't work for keras. The below is my first codes and they all didn't work.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import RepeatVector
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
```

But after I changed to the following below, they all work like others above.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import RepeatVector
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).